# Cannot update multiple select inputs in shiny at the same time in the first time

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which has multiple `selectInput` and need to be dynamically updated. The R codes below show a minimum example to reproduce my question.

There are two selectInput and one button. The default value is `A1` for `A` and `B1` for `B`. I will update `A` into `A2`, `B` into `B4` when I click the button. However, the `B` becomes `B3` in the first click (wrong result), but `B4` at the second click (correct result).

It is really strange behavior. How could I fix this problem? Thanks for any suggestions.

PS: I installed the latest version of shiny in github.

Screenshots for three stages (initial, first click, second click).

[image]

Example codes to reproduce my problem.

```
library(shiny)
df <- data.frame(
    A = c('A1', 'A1', 'A2',  'A2'),
    B = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# Shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('sel1', 'A', choices = NULL, 
                  selected = NULL, 
                  selectize = FALSE)
    , selectInput('sel2', 'B', choices = NULL, 
                  selected = NULL, 
                  selectize = FALSE)
    , actionButton('clickme',  'Click me')
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        df_a <- unique(df$A)
        updateSelectInput(session, 'sel1', choices = df_a, selected = NULL)
    })
    observe({
        req(input$sel1)
        df_b <- df[df$A == input$sel1,]
        df_b <- unique(df_b$B)
        updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', choices = df_b, selected = NULL)
    })
    observe({
        req(input$clickme)
        updateSelectInput(session, 'sel1', selected = 'A2')

        updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', selected = 'B4')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why your code has this special behaviour: Lets go through what happens after you clicked the button.

First:

```
# Status: 
# sel1 : choices : "A1", "A2", selected : "A1"
# sel2 : choices : "B1", "B2", selected : "B1"
observe({
  req(input$clickme)
  updateSelectInput(session, 'sel1', selected = 'A2')

  updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', selected = 'B4')
})
```

You manage to set `sel1` to `A2`. But at the moment, `sel2` does not have the choice `B4`, so it is set to `NULL`.

Second, since `input$sel1` was updated, this fires:

```
# Status: 
# sel1 : choices : "A1", "A2", selected : "A2"
# sel2 : choices : "B1", "B2", selected : NULL
observe({
  req(input$sel1)
  df_b <- df[df$A == input$sel1,]
  df_b <- unique(df_b$B)

  updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', choices = df_b, selected = NULL)
})
```

Now, `sel2` is updated to choices `B3` and `B4` and since you selected `NULL`, it automatically takes the first value in its choices, `B3`.

Here is what happens after you click the button a second time. As expected, this fires:

```
# Status: 
# sel1 : choices : "A1", "A2", selected : "A2"
# sel2 : choices : "B3", "B4", selected : "B3"
observe({
  req(input$clickme)
  updateSelectInput(session, 'sel1', selected = 'A2')

  updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', selected = 'B4')
})
```

Now, both selections are valid and you end up with `A2` and `B4`. And since `sel1` was previously set to `A2`, there is no change in `input$sel1`, which is why the second observer does not trigger this time.

You can confirm this by adding `observe({print(input$sel2)})` to your server. This gives the output

```
NULL
[1] "B1"
NULL
[1] "B3"
[1] "B4"
```

### Edit

Now I had some time to think of a solution. From what I wrote above, it is clear that it cannot work the way you wrote your code. That is because whenever you try to set `sel1` and `sel2` in the same observer, `sel2` will be reset afterwards (if `sel1` changes). You'd need some kind of schedule: 1) set `sel1` then 2) (possibly) update `sel2` then 3) set `sel2`.

The following is a solution that does "delay" the setting of `sel2` like I suggested. It might however not be the prettiest solution, but that lies in the twisted nature of the problem. It mainly checks the set-value for `sel2` before it updates it. And depending on whether `sel2` will be updated, it applies changes immediately or leaves it to the `sel2 - update.

```
library(shiny)
df <- data.frame(
  A = c('A1', 'A1', 'A2',  'A2'),
  B = c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# Shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('sel1', 'A', choices = NULL, 
              selected = NULL, 
              selectize = FALSE)
  , selectInput('sel2', 'B', choices = NULL, 
                selected = NULL, 
                selectize = FALSE)
  , actionButton('clickme',  'Click me')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  choice <- NULL

  observe({
    df_a <- unique(df$A)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'sel1', choices = df_a, selected = NULL)
  })
  observe({
    req(input$sel1)
    df_b <- df[df$A == input$sel1,]
    df_b <- unique(df_b$B)

    updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', choices = df_b, selected = choice)

    choice <<- NULL
  })
  observe({
    req(input$clickme)
    updateSelectInput(session, 'sel1', selected = 'A2')

    choice <<- "B4"

    # build the set of current sel2-choices

    df_b <- df[df$A == isolate(input$sel1),]
    df_b <- unique(df_b$B)

    if(choice %in% df_b){
      updateSelectInput(session, 'sel2', choices = df_b, selected = choice)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I get your points. Do you have any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: Answer edited. See if this fix can help you. It's rather improvised.